# ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in PlayersController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating first rails app and had everything working yesterday.  I created association on my view today for players to pull to team page with has_many and belongs_to.  Now I can not create a new player as it keeps giving me an ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in PlayersController#create message.

Extracted source (around line #27):

```
  def create
    @player = Player.create(params[:player])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @player.save
```

Parameters:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"uw5w2sOgNF6y3+Jv6kvTj3X/dV2+PAVo2/OyHinIirY=",
 "player"=>{"first_name"=>"test",
 "last_name"=>"",
 "address_1"=>"",
 "address_2"=>"",
 "city"=>"",
 "state"=>"",
 "zip"=>"",
 "phone_number"=>"",
 "email"=>"",
 "birthday"=>"",
 "position"=>"",
 "bio"=>"",
 "team"=>"",
 "team_id"=>"1",
 "number"=>""},
 "commit"=>"Create Player"}
```

My players controller for create is:

def create
    @player = Player.new(player_params)

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @player.save
    format.html { redirect_to @player, notice: 'Player was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @player }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'new' }
    format.json { render json: @player.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

Comment: Hi Benjamin...thank you for the response.  That did not seem to do it.  I have the player_params set as params.require already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are supposed to have this `player_params` method in your controller, and use it to pass the params to your model actions (create, update)

```
class PlayersController
  ...
  def create
    @player = Player.create(player_params)
    ...
  end

  private

  def player_params
    allow = [:first_name, :last_name, :address_1, :address_2, :city, :state, :zip, :phone_number, :email, :birthday, :position, :bio, :team, :team_id, :number]
    params.require(:player).permit(allow)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you Benjamin...that one did it.

Answer (score 1):

I've been going crazy searching for a solution for this, when I already had applied the params.require bit.  So for people who are using **cancan**, you need to add this part to the ApplicationController:

See: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/issues/571

```
before_filter do
  resource = controller_name.singularize.to_sym
  method = "#{resource}_params"
  params[resource] &&= send(method) if respond_to?(method, true)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class PlayersController

   ...

 def create
     @player = Player.new(player_params)

   ...

  end

 private

 def player_params

   params.require(:player).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :address_1, :address_2, :city, :state, :zip, :phone_number, :email, :birthday, :position, :bio, :team, :team_id, :number)

   end

end
```

Comment: So... this is essentially 100% the same as the other answer, just with more blank lines?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Rails 4 and you've added `player_params` method, don't forget to change `params[:player]` in your create method to just `player_params`.